# Commiting changes accross projects in Visual Studio 2008 with Git Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, git, git-extensions

Imagine a solution in Visual Studio 2008 that consists of three projects. Two of them are file-system wise located under the solution home directory and a third one that has been added via *Add Existing project* from a location outside the solution.

The first two projects are part of the git repository covering the solution directory while the third one has its own git repository since it is simply a utility library shared accross several solutions.

My problem is that I can commit changes to git in Visual Studio by selecting a file or folder in one of the projects but I am unable to commit all changes to all projects by selecting the Root Node in the Solution Explorer. I am fully aware that this would imply a multi-repo commit performed by Git Extensions. But still does anyone know how to do this or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since they are separated repositories.

The best solution that is available, is to add the second repository as a submodule to the first repository. This will not make committing any easier, but it will allow you checkout an old revision for both repositories, without manually having to find the corresponding commit in the second repository.